# Can't make my application appear in the share sheet

Tags: swift4, ios13

I have created share extension, it was working fine with me till I updated Xcode iOS13 and suddenly my app disappeared from the share sheet and I have tried everything.

I created a new application and took the exact info.plist there and still didn't work, I tried even deleting the old share extension and creating new one and didn't work, although when I create an entirely  new project it works fine with me.